# Is it better to have one or two REST endpoints for this scenario?

Tags: api, rest, microservices

I have a microservice that handles the bookings process. Half of the data is on a db **bookings** table and half within an external 3rd party service that is required for completing the booking.

From a REST perspective is it better to expose 2 endpoints on the same microservice each for each case ie

```
POST /bookings (pass relevant data)
POST /external-service/bookings (pass relevant data)
```

or one

```
POST /bookings (pass all data for both cases)
```

That does create a new record in the **bookings** db table but also talks with the external service API to complete the booking?

Personally I am leaning towards the second approach.

Answer (score 1):

From a REST perspective, it is generally recommended to have a single endpoint for each resource, in this case, the `bookings` is the resource.

The second approach, where you have one endpoint for creating a booking and it handles both saving to the database and interacting with the external service, would be more consistent with REST principles.

```
POST /bookings (pass all data for both cases)
```

It allows for better separation of concerns as the microservice is responsible for handling the booking resource, and it doesn't expose the details of how the booking is completed to the client. Additionally, it eliminates the need for the client to make multiple requests to different endpoints to complete a single action.

However, this approach may make testing and debugging more challenging if the external service is not available or if the external service is required to be updated.